# TextView not getting inline with other view

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

[image: TextView not getting inline]

In this i tried numerous way to bring pay and recieve in vertical line with hello world , but every thing failed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>




<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.ubschallenge.drawable.MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pay"
            android:layout_marginBottom="110dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_above="@id/button"

            />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pay"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/pay"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/recieve"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Recieve"
            android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/button"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

This above is the code . I want to make it look like TEZ Payment app home screen

EDIT :  After clicking hello world

[image: After clicking hello world]

Expected output :[image: Expected output]

Khalal Output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DvfX.png)

Khaled Updated answers output:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNKAr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using `ConstraintLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button"
        android:text="Pay"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_top" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recieve"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Recieve"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />



    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Update 1**

- Make use of [`Guideline`](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) with [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

**Update 2**

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"

        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.75"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

- And try to **update** `layout_constraintHeight_percent` and `layout_constraintGuide_percent` of top and bottom `Guidline` to achieve your Goal.

Comment: it also dint worked , i am attaching the output in question of your answer

Comment: khaled can you help me out ?

Comment: it still did not worked.I have put the output of your updated code in question

Comment: @RushabhOswal Check my **Update 2** Hope that help you to manage your problem, Have a nice day!